# Low performance of subsequent query with the same table using UCanAccess

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am trying to update approx. 3800 rows in a table in two steps:

1. set all values to 0
2. set some of them in a loop to a calculated value

The first step is fast (< 1 s). However the second step takes around 3 s. Maybe there is some problem in the code, because if I run the code without the first step or run the first query on another table, the second step is very fast, too (< 0.1 s). It is slow only when executed after the first step on the same table.

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" 
        + path +;singleconnection=true" ,"", ""); 

// First update (reset all values)
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();         
PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE mytab SET val = 0.0;"); 
ps2.executeUpdate();
ps2.close();
System.out.println("Update 1: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000.0 + " s");

// Second update
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
int count = 0;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE mytab SET val = ? WHERE id = ?;");

for(int j= 1; j <= 3600; j++){
      double value;
      // calculate some value ....
      value = 1.3;
      // update table under certain conditions
      if(true){
              ps.setDouble(1, value);
              ps.setInt(2, j);
              ps.addBatch();
              count++;
       }
       if(count > 200){
               ps.executeBatch();
               count = 0;
        }
}
ps.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
System.out.println("Update 2: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000.0 + " s");
```

Why does the second step take so long? How to avoid this?

(I asked the same question [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/a7feb44e/) already but without success).

**Edit**:
If I try the two queries with the old JDBC-ODBC bridge (and Java 7) the second query is very fast (< 1 s) when executed after the first. So I think it must be some UCanAccess problem.

Comment: Instead of `value = 1.3;` try `value = ((Long) start).doubleValue();` to ensure that you are always updating rows even if you are not zeroing them out first. Your test may be deceiving you because if the row remains unchanged, e.g., by running the same test twice in succession with the same `value`, then it won't be written back to the database file and the second run will finish much faster than the first..

Comment: BTW, what does MySQL have to do with this?

Comment: @GordThompson: Uuuh, true, the test is misleading, just didn't realize 
before!! (Real) updates take around 3 s either way.

Any ideas how to speed it up? With JDBC-ODBC its much faster.

Comment: It has of course nothing to do with mysql, deleted that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As determined in the comments to the question, the original test was deceiving because when the first query zeroed out the values it forced the second query to update every row. However, when the first query was omitted the second query was simply "updating" the rows with the existing test value. Since the rows were not actually being changed they were not flushed out to the database file so the second query ran much faster. A tweak to the test value which forced the rows to be updated by the second query resulted in the same performance whether or not the first query was executed.

As for the performance of the updates, instead of directly updating each row you might find it faster to

- create a temporary table,
- insert the new values into the temporary table,
- merge the temporary table into the main table, and then
- drop the temporary table.

I just tried this and it seems to run in about a quarter of the time required to directly update the main table row-by-row:

```java
StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
sw.start();
try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    st.execute("CREATE TABLE zzzTemp (id LONG, val DOUBLE)");
}
double newDbl = ((Long) System.currentTimeMillis()).doubleValue();  // test data
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO zzzTemp (id, val) VALUES (?,?)")) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3600; i++) {
        ps.setInt(1, i);
        ps.setDouble(2, newDbl);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
}
System.out.printf("Overall elapsed time: %d ms%n", sw.getTime());
try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    st.execute("MERGE INTO mytab m USING zzzTemp z ON m.id = z.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET m.val = z.val");
    System.out.printf("Overall elapsed time: %d ms%n", sw.getTime());
    st.execute("DROP TABLE zzzTemp");
    System.out.printf("Overall elapsed time: %d ms%n", sw.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Works great and really fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you have a loop EXTERNAL from mysql. The calling program keeps calling the same prepared statement, but each call/execution has a lot of overhead, even if the actual statement is small.

The ideal solution is to move the condition to SQL (if feasible) and let mysql handle it. In that case, it's usually very fast:

```
UPDATE mytab SET value=1.3 WHERE <condition>;
```

In fact , you could combine the two with an IF statement (again, if mysql has the proper data for the condition:

```
UPDATE mytab SET value=IF(<condition>, 1.3, 0.0)
```

--- EDIT ---
If you have transactions active, then the first query sets aside all the records and each subsequent query will have to modify an existing (live transaction). You'll have 3800 transaction conflicts. Try putting a COMMIT between the two queries

Comment: That avoids a second query on the same table and will be much faster, true, but 1. I wouldn't like to do it because the condition is not in the database and 2. it does not explain why the second query is so much slower when preceded by the first one.

Comment: Every time you call
              ps.setDouble(1, value);
              ps.setInt(2, j);
              ps.addBatch();
your program has to connect to mysql, be validated, identify the query to be executed, execute the query with the parameters, <update the db as before>, send status back to the app, close the socket.
All the other steps are overhead from the program to the mysql engine. They all take time.
It's like going to the store to buy 3000 items, or going 3000 times to the store to buy 1 item at a time. Purchasing (executing) takes the same amount of time; but the travel takes time

Comment: Just re-read your question properly. If you have transactions active, then the first query sets aside all the records and each subsequent query will have to modify an existing (live transaction).
Try putting a COMMIT between the two queries

Comment: I tried to expicitly commit after the first query, but now change. Anyway, the transaction is started AFTER the first query, so there should not be a conflict with the first query.

Comment: Loved @Gord Thompson catch. Stupid question: Does the fact that you have executeBatch every 200 records have anything to do with it? Meaning, if you just have one ps.executeBatch(); in your original query change the speed?

Comment: Executing every 200 records does not improve speed here. Its usefull for larger total record numbers. The code is just a simplified example.